# cbind/join data frames of different lengths without identifier

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to `cbind`/`join` two data frames that do not have a unique identifier.  The format is complex due to how they were webscraped.

`df1` contains assay results, with 1 row for each assay occurring on a day, and a row (ID, Name, Concentration) separating assays from different days. `df2` contains 1 row for each assay date.  I need to bind assay dates from `df2` to `df1`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c("ID", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "ID", "1", "2", "3", "ID", "1", "2"),
                  X2 = c("Name", "Jose", "Mary", "Doug", "Luisa", "Pam", "Name", "Jose", "Doug", "Lou", "Name", "Luisa", "Pam"),
                  X3 = c("Concentration", "4.2", "2.3", "7.3", "1.4", "0.5", "Concentration", "0.1", "2.3", "2.1", "Concentration", "9.0", "1.4"))
df2 <- data.frame(X4 = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"),
                  X5 = c("January", "February", "March"),
                  X6 = c("12", "4", "21"))
```

I want the resulting data frame to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSnuh.png).

So far, I have tried to create an identifier for assays occurring on the same date, but I have not been successful because the number of assays in a day varies greatly.  In reality, I have more than 200,000 assays from dozens of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `which` and `diff` to determine the number of assays on each date, then go from there:

```r
w <- which(df1$X1 == "ID")
n <- diff(c(w, nrow(df1) + 1L))
df3 <- data.frame(df1, df2[rep.int(seq_along(n), n), ])
df3
```

```
    X1    X2            X3      X4       X5 X6
1   ID  Name Concentration  Monday  January 12
1.1  1  Jose           4.2  Monday  January 12
1.2  2  Mary           2.3  Monday  January 12
1.3  3  Doug           7.3  Monday  January 12
1.4  4 Luisa           1.4  Monday  January 12
1.5  5   Pam           0.5  Monday  January 12
2   ID  Name Concentration Tuesday February  4
2.1  1  Jose           0.1 Tuesday February  4
2.2  2  Doug           2.3 Tuesday February  4
2.3  3   Lou           2.1 Tuesday February  4
3   ID  Name Concentration  Friday    March 21
3.1  1 Luisa           9.0  Friday    March 21
3.2  2   Pam           1.4  Friday    March 21
```

But for analysis in R, a data frame with non-redundant rows and correct data types will be much more useful.  I'd recommend something like this instead:

```r
w <- which(df1$X1 == "ID")
n <- diff(c(w, nrow(df1) + 1L)) - 1L
df3 <- data.frame(ID = df1$X1[-w],
                  Name = df1$X2[-w],
                  Concentration = as.double(df1$X3[-w]),
                  Date = rep.int(as.Date(paste(2023L, match(df2$X5, month.name), as.integer(df2$X6), sep = "-")), n))
df3
```

```
   ID  Name Concentration       Date
1   1  Jose           4.2 2023-01-12
2   2  Mary           2.3 2023-01-12
3   3  Doug           7.3 2023-01-12
4   4 Luisa           1.4 2023-01-12
5   5   Pam           0.5 2023-01-12
6   1  Jose           0.1 2023-02-04
7   2  Doug           2.3 2023-02-04
8   3   Lou           2.1 2023-02-04
9   1 Luisa           9.0 2023-03-21
10  2   Pam           1.4 2023-03-21
```